# Eigenvector of a markov chain - relation to initial conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

Something I'm a bit confused about when it comes to Markov chains is how the initial vector relates to the eigenvector. Suppose the transformation matrix is $\vec{A}$. From my understanding, we are looking to find a vector $\vec{v}$ which has the equality:

$$\vec{v}*\vec{A}=\vec{v}$$

In other words (and please correct me if I'm wrong), we are trying to find the eigenvector of $\vec{A}$ with a corresponding eigenvalue of 1. However, this is not dependent on initial conditions $\vec{v_0}$ - I get how the iterative approach will get to a stable equilibrium (and uses the initial vector as the starting point), but with exact solutions, how does the eigenvector then take us from our initial condition vector to the stable equilibrium vector?

Comment: Write the initial condition as a sum over all eigenvectors of $A$. After applying $A$ many times typically the components corresponding to all other eigenvectors vanish, because their eigenvalues are less than $1$ in absolute value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'm more talking about how if we determined the eigenvector of $\vec{A}$ with an eigenvalue of 1, how what do we do with that to get our stable equilibrium vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the iterations $$v_{i+1}^T=v_i^TA$$

If $v_i$ indicates the probability distribution of states at time $i$, then $v_{i+1}$ indicate the distribution of states at time $i+1$.

In fact, convergence is not guaraneteed. For example, consider $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, suppose we let $v_0=\begin{bmatrix} 0.3 \\ 0.7\end{bmatrix}$, we can observe that the sequence of vectors will just iterate between $\begin{bmatrix} 0.3 \\ 0.7\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0.7 \\ 0.3\end{bmatrix}$ and hence it doesn't conveges. This is true for almost all the vectors besides $v_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 0.5 \\ 0.5\end{bmatrix}$.

Hence, the initial distribution does decide whether it converges and if so to which equilibrium distribution. There are also cases where equilibrium solution is unique and it is independent of initial distribution.

Short answer when things are nice:

Let's consider the special case where $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A^n =B$ exists.

Notice that $B$ has the property that $BA=B$.

Let's consider the vector $y^T=v_0^TB$.

Then, $y^TA = v_0^TBA=v_0^TB=y^T$

Hence $y$ is an eigenvector. Each row of $B$ is a distribution and $v_0$ decides the weight for combinations of such distributions. In the events that each row of $B$ is identical, then it is independent of the choice of $v_0$. Ergodic unichain guarantees that each row of $B$ is identical.

Comment: Thank you!!!! So how do I go from the corresponding eigenvector to the actual distribution?

Comment: The eigenvectors is the equilibrium distribution of being in that state.

Comment: So in order to compute the actual values of $v_\infty$, would I just do $v_0^Ty$, where $y$ is the eigenvector with $\lambda = 1$?

Comment: If you are sure that there is exactly one such eigenvector. we can just compute it directly. Otherwise, I will examine the classes and see if they are periodic or aperiodic. Also I will check if they are transient or recurrent and work from there.

Comment: So if we are sure of this eigenvector, how do we compute $v_\infty$? Or if you have a concrete example I'd appreciate that.

Comment: $A^Tv = v$. Solve $(A^T-I)v = 0$ which is just a linear system.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think we're on the same page. I understand how to compute the eigenvector. But let's say we find the distinct eigenvector of matrix $A$ with eigenvalue 1. Let's call that $k$. This implies $Ak = k$. I have an initial distribution $v_0$. How do I use $k$ to find $v_\infty$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61575/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-rb612).