# RREF - two columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I'm starting out working with RREF and I wanted to work through an example problem. One was to compute the reduced row echelon form of the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\-1 & 2\\-3 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm a bit confused, because if I'm understanding correctly, this is supposed to be an augmented matrix (so I can technically draw a line down the middle in this case to make it clearer).

But that would mean that it corresponds to a system as follows:

$$-x_1=1$$
$$-x_1=2$$
$$-3x_1=2$$

And when I did the reduction, I got:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

So that would correspond with $x_1 =0$ but $0 = 1$ so from my understanding, the solution is inconsistent? I'm wondering if a) I interpreted the augmented matrix correctly and the corresponding system aligns with the matrix, and b) if the fact that row 2 is $0\  \ \ \ 1$  means that it's inconsistent?

Comment: How do you know that this is an augmented matrix? It could just as well correspond to the homogeneous system $y-x=0$, $2y-x=0$, $2y-3x=0$, which is consistent, although it has only the trivial solution. For a homogeneous system of linear equations, there’s not much point in augmenting the coefficient matrix by a column of zeros since those zeros are unchanged any elementary row operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the RREF is indeed correct.

$$0=1$$ implies that the system is inconsistent.

Remark: to further convince yourself that it is indeed inconsistent. The first equation says that $x_1=-1$ btu the second equation says that $x_1=-2$. $-1=-2$ is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I thought, but I wasn't sure if I was doing any of this correctly because I had never seen a two-column augmented matrix without an explicit divider.

Comment: oh, just include a dividor if it helps.

Comment: btw, to play safe, is that resources available online? or can you take a screen shot?

Comment: Sure! #2 on https://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~thomas/Courses/RREF_Practice.pdf - It was one of the first things when I looked up RREF practice :)

Comment: I see. RREF is not just defined for augemented matrix. It is defined for arbitrary matrix. That exercise is just a practice to reduce a matrix to its RREF form. but your interpretation is correct when it is an augmented matrix (usually we will draw a vertical line between the two matrices).

Comment: Thank you!! If you have the chance, I'd really appreciate if you checked out my other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336403/eigenvector-of-a-markov-chain-relation-to-initial-conditions - you seem to explain this well.